# Merge in SQL . Is it better than if exists?

Tags: sql

I have the following SP, is it feasible to use MERGE or should i go with basic If Exists

```
create procedure Test
   @DocumentTypeId int,
   @PAdmissionID int,
   @UMStatusID int,
   @UserId int,
   @DocumentType varchar(50)
   as
   Begin 

 Merge  [dbo].Test T
 Using (select DocumentTypeId,DocumentType from UMStatusToAdmissionLink where PAdmissionID = @PAdmissionID and UserID = @UserId) as S
 On(@DocumentTypeId = S.DocumentTypeId and @DocumentType = S.DocumentType and T.PAdmissionID = S.AdmissionID)
 When Matched
 Then Update set UMStatusId = @UMStatusID;
   End
```

Our environment has : Replication , Lot of traffic , Do merge handle concurrency?

Comment: what db server are you using?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MERGE` is designed to perform both an `UPDATE` and an `INSERT` in one T-SQL command.  If you are just doing `UPDATE`s then just do an `UPDATE`.

I don't think you need an `IF EXISTS`. You can just put the condition in the `WHERE` clause. If nothing matches the condition, then nothing will get updated.

Comment: DDL? As in Data Definition Language?